# Git file renaming produces Error: "warning: destination exists; will overwrite!"

Tags: git, shell

I want to rename my file in my repository locally. So I do:

```
git mv -f hashpq.py HashPQ.py
```

And get this:

```
warning: destination exists; will overwrite!
```

Then I get the status of git by:

```
git status
```

And get thisresponse:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    hashpq.py
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   hashpq.py
```

But after I list my directory by:

```
ls
```

I have this:

```
CHANGLELOG  hashpq.py  NEXTPLAN  README  TODO
```

I still have hashpq.py unchanged with previous name.
How can I rename the file to HashPQ.py?

Comment: git 2.0.1+ (which will be available with msysgit soon https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/, but not on Cygwin yet, https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/git/) avoids that issue. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979082/6309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My file system was NTFS and as you know it s case insensitive for file names basically.
Thus, I need to first change it to asghar.py first and then change it to HashPQ.py.

Thanks all.

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595491/4518341)? What is different about this? If not, what's the significance of the name "asghar"?

Answer (score 7):

Try renaming it to some temporary name, and then to the name you want:

```
git mv hashpq.py _hashpq.py
git mv _hashpq.py HashPQ.py
git commit
```

This is the same behaviour as the regular `mv` command when the file system is case-insensitive.

Comment: No. I ll get the same while trying to change even to _hashpq.py. I can change hashpq.py to HashPQ.py easily out of repository. I dont understand.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. My flash USB containing my repository has NTFS file system. Thus it s case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need `-f` anymore, with git 2.0.1 (June 25yh, 2014).

A `git mv hashpq.py HashPQ.py` will just work on case insensitive OS, as detailed in [commit baa37bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/baa37bff9a845471754d3f47957d58a6ccc30058) by [David Turner (`dturner-tw`)](https://github.com/dturner-tw)

#### `mv`: allow renaming to fix case on case insensitive filesystems

"`git mv hello.txt Hello.txt`" on a case insensitive filesystem always triggers "`destination already exists`" error, because these two names refer to the same path from the filesystem's point of view, and requires the user to give "`--force`" when correcting the case of the path recorded in the index and in the next commit.

> Detect this case and allow it without requiring "`--force`".